# Protecting files from the network

Tags: file-sharing

I need to protect the project files in the local server . It should be accessable for all . Employees can  access and modifiy it and they can create new files . The thing which i want to do is protecting the files copying by the employess. These project files are shared in the local network. I have almost done everything but i couldnt get the exact solution.

Comment: If they can modify a file how do you expect to prevent them from copying?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. If they can access the files, they can copy the files. After all, accessing the files is a form of copying; you are copying the files into RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Chris is right, you can't do this using only the native tools.

If you're willing to consider 3rd party tools, our product FileSure does a pretty good job at this.  We do it by preventing the users from 'Misusing' the files in the first place.

For example, if you block Windows Explorer the ability to READ a file, you'll stop 95% of users copying files.  Or you could take the other side and prevent '*.xlsx' (for example) from being created on Workstations.

I hope that's helpful and not too much of a product plug.